# Picasso Library not downloading full image in android on network state change

Tags: android, picasso, imagedownload

I am using Picasso library in my android application but when i change the network state the image is half downloaded.Please suggest me something so that image always fully downloaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Listen-er to the network connection status. You can resolve it by reloading it if the requirement is met.

Comment: In picasso library if image is downloaded then that half image is only come from cache and if i clear the cache then i will lost all the bitmaps which was downloaded earlier.